# Division of nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, nested-loops

I have two dictionaries. one is a nested dictionary and another one is general dictionary. I want to do some divisions:

`dict1 = {'document1': {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 5}, 'document2': {'d': 2, 'e': 4}}`

`dict2 = {'document1': 28, 'document2': 36}`

I want to use the inner dictionary values form dict1 to divided by the value of matching document in dict2. The expect output would be:
enter code here

`dict3 = {'document1': {'a': 3/28, 'b': 1/28, 'c': 5/28}, 'document2': {'d': 2/36, 'e': 4/36}}`

I tried using two for loop to run each dictionary, but values will be duplicate multiple times and I have no idea how to fix this? Does anyone has idea of how to achieve this goal? I would be appreciate it!``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using dictionary comprehension.

```
dict3 = {} # create a new dictionary


# iterate dict1 keys, to get value from dict2, which will be used to divide dict 1 values

for d in dict1:
       y  = dict2[d] 
       dict3[d] = {k:(v/y) for k, v in dict1[d].items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
dict1 = {'document1': {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': 5},
         'document2': {'d': 2, 'e': 4}}

dict2 = {'document1': 28, 'document2': 36}

for k,v in dict1.items():
    for ki,vi in v.items():
        dict1[k][ki] /= dict2[k]
print(dict1)
# output
#{'document1': {'a': 0.10714285714285714, 'b': 0.03571428571428571, 'c': 0.17857142857142858}, 
#'document2': {'d': 0.05555555555555555, 'e': 0.1111111111111111}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line, using nested dictionary comprehensions:

```
dict3 = {doc_key: {k: (v/doc_value) for k, v in dict1[doc_key].items()} for doc_key, doc_value in dict2.items()}
```